# What is the problem with debugShowMaterialGrid? See Details

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am having trouble with getting `debugShowMaterialGrid` recognized by Android Studio while developing a Flutter application. I have the Flutter plugin installed and everything.

My code looks like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';


void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled=true;
  debugShowMaterialGrid=true; //doesn't recognize debugShowMaterialGrid
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Is there any packages I forgot to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a property on `MaterialApp`, and must be set when you construct the material app. For example:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowMaterialGrid: true,
      // etc
```